# x11vnc constantly closing in 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop

I've been using this remote desktop solution several years ago, but seems to be a problem with the latest Ubuntu. It closes constantly when remote connecting. Hoy can I find where the problem is? Should I search for a .log or something?

I tried with several x11vnc -options and all hangs.
And tried the 'apt install lightdm' solutions posted here but didn't work

Comment: x11vnc is expected to close when the viewer closes.  Did you try the --forever option?

Comment: Yes, I tried it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [setup protocol](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12220) and repeated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685761/x11vnc-service-is-running-but-client-can%C2%B4t-find-server). It works pretty well. I can connect via RealVNC and MAC screen share. The last one doesn't work that well though.