# x11vnc refuses connection after upgrade form ubuntu 18.04 to 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, xorg, vnc

I have originally set up x11vnc server according to [main source](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12220) or [also repeated here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685761/x11vnc-service-is-running-but-client-can%C2%B4t-find-server).

The server seems to start properly, see below.

```
    user:~$ sudo systemctl status x11vnc.service
● x11vnc.service - Start x11vnc at startup.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-08-08 13:22:39 EDT; 9min ago
 Main PID: 2312 (x11vnc)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/x11vnc.service
           └─2312 /usr/bin/x11vnc -loop -forever -bg -rfbport 5900 -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -shared -norc -aut
```

However, I get the message "The connection was refused by the computer" if I try to connect to it.

I have found that the port 5900 is not open: the command

```
sudo lsof -i :5900,3389
```

results in nothing

Does anyone know what could have happened?

Comment: Could anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Maybe try without the password for x11vnc?  Also, Xubuntu still uses lightdm, so that may be easier to set up, as the articles claim.